# Apple Script Can't get Safari menu

Tags: macos, safari, applescript

I'm trying below scripts for syncing Safari's bookmark with Chrome's bookmark on Mac.
However, I got this error as:
"System Events got an error: Can’t get menu item "Google Chrome.app…" of menu "Import From" of menu item "Import From" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of process "Safari"."
I think the menu names are correct and don't have any idea what is wrong...please give me any advice. Thanks.

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Safari"
                tell menu bar 1
                    tell menu bar item "File"
                        tell menu "File"
                            tell menu item "Import From"
                                tell menu "Import From"
                                    click menu item "Google Chrome.app…"
                                    delay 0.5
                                    keystroke return
                                end tell
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

The menu item does not have `.app`, so should be :

```
click menu item "Google Chrome…"
```

Comment: Thank for the answer. I changed the menu item name, but it still says
"System Events got an error: Can’t get menu item "Google Chrome…" of menu "Import From" of menu item "Import From" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of process "Safari"."
I have no idea what's wrong....

Comment: Can you see `menu item "Google Chrome…"` when you do it manually in `Safari` ?

Answer (score 0):

Everything that has been said so far is not enough.

GUI scripting should exactly repeat the user's **clicks** performed manually. No menu will open until the script clicks on the corresponding menu bar item or on the corresponding menu item.

Opening each menu is like opening a window. Therefore, you need to add a time delay - for stability. Here, I added **automated delays**:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    set frontmost to true
    tell menu bar 1 to tell menu bar item "File"
        click it -- important click
        repeat until menu "File" exists -- important delay
            delay 0.2
        end repeat
        tell menu "File" to tell menu item "Import From"
            click it -- important click
            repeat until menu "Import From" exists -- important delay
                delay 0.2
            end repeat
            tell menu "Import From" to click menu item "Google Chrome.app…"
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: On my Ventura (13.2.1), your script gave same error.

Comment: This script was created and tested on Catalina.

Comment: Just for reference, my error : `execution error: System Events got an error: Can’t get menu item "Google Chrome.app…" of menu "Import From" of menu item "Import From" of menu "File" of menu bar item "File" of menu bar 1 of process "Safari". (-1728`